# Assign multiple variables in a collective string - python

Tags: python

I have a file containing a long list of variable assignments (about 50) as a collective string. I need to turn them into python assignments but eval() and exec() both fail. How do I do this without having to strip() the data from every single one of those lines?

Sample of contents in "variables.txt" file:

```
# Program Settings

simulation = True                    # Enables/disables sending transactions
bugCheck = False                     # Prints errors to console in details
fontColor = True                     # Enables/disables font color in console
dispSummary = True                   # Displays system and configuration summary
```

Attempts to read and assign variables in "program.py":

```
with open('variables.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

variables = eval(data) # Failed (SyntaxError: invalid syntax, '=') 
variables = exec(data) # Returns None
```

Comment: Is the file supposed to be written in Python syntax? If so, rename it to .py and import it as a module.

Comment: Or just read each line, skip blank lines and comments, and split it at `=`. It's not hard, that's what you use a programming language for.

Comment: @mkrieger1 your first suggestion sounds like the most convenient soln. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
variables = exec(data)
```

This works and does evaluate the Python code in your file. However, it does not return anything, but brings everything defined in `data` in scope.

You can e.g. do

```py
with open('variables.txt', 'r') as f:
    data = f.read()

exec(data)

if simulation: # `simulation` is defined in your external file. The definition is executed in the call to `exec`
    print("This is a simulation")
```

and it does indeed print the string.